# Delete one of the time dimensions from a 3-D DataArray in Python?

Tags: multidimensional-array, time-series, netcdf, python-xarray

I have a `DataArray` as follow:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'tws' (time: 179, lat: 180, lon: 360)>
[11599200 values with dtype=float64]
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2002-04-18 ... 2019-11-15T17:00:01
  * lon      (lon) float32 -179.5 -178.5 -177.5 -176.5 ... 177.5 178.5 179.5
  * lat      (lat) float32 89.5 88.5 87.5 86.5 85.5 ... -86.5 -87.5 -88.5 -89.5
```

I need to remove one of the time dimensions (e.g. `tws['time'][23]`), and at the end I expect to have a data with the shape of  `(time: 178, lat: 180, lon: 360)`

I know we can use .sel and .slice to select a particular range of data as follow:

```
tws.time.sel(time=slice[('2018-11-15T17:00:01.000000000')])
```

But in my case, I would like to have all the data except one (or more) specific time dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.drop_sel` method:

```
tws.drop_sel(time=slice[('2018-11-15T17:00:01.000000000')])
```

Edit: remove `time` from `tws.time`

Comment: The characteristics of time variable that I wand to remove it is as follow: 

`<xarray.DataArray 'time' ()>
array('2018-11-15T17:00:01.000000000', dtype='datetime64[ns]')

Coordinates:
    time     datetime64[ns] 2018-11-15T17:00:01

Attributes:
    standard_name:  time
    axis:           T`


When I run your code I will get the following error:

`TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: How's that change?

Comment: still the same error.
`'type' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: even I tried this  `tws = tws.where((tws.time[-13]) , drop=True)`  ; although I didn't get any error, but the dataset doesn't change, and it remains as before.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: `tws = 'D:\\G3P\\DATA\\TWS1degree\\L3_TWS_Corr.nc4'`

`data = xr.open_dataset(tws)`

when running `data.tws` it shows the variable and the coordinates as follow: 

`<xarray.DataArray 'tws' (time: 179, lat: 180, lon: 360)>
[11599200 values with dtype=float64]
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2002-04-18 ... 2019-11-15T17:00:01
  * lon      (lon) float32 -179.5 -178.5 -177.5 -176.5 ... 177.5 178.5 179.5
  * lat      (lat) float32 89.5 88.5 87.5 86.5 85.5 ... -86.5 -87.5 -88.5 -89.5`

Comment: It's not reproducible if it's on `D:`! You'll need an actually reproducible example, even with toy data, i.e. https://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports